# creating a bean only after specific method was called

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

is it possible to create a bean in Spring only after a specific method was called? let's say that I have a method called beforeActual() and in that method I call another method Actual() and I want to create a bean out of Actual() method but only after it was called in BeforeActual() method. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1):

What I needed to do was to simply put @Lazy above the method with @Bean annotation and @Configuration above class this initializes a annotead bean only a method with @Bean annonation is called